# C programming while loop and array structure

Tags: c, arrays

So I have a ton of code here:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#define max 100
typedef enum { diploma, bachelor, master, doctor } education;

struct person {                    // a node to hold personal details
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
    int phone;
    education degree;

};

struct person directory[max];                // an array of structures, 100 entries
int tail = 0;                         // global variable

void flush();                         // forward declaration of functions
void branching(char c);
int insertion();
int print_person(int i);
int print_all();
int search_person();
int delete_person();


int main() {  // print a menu for selection
    char ch = 'i';

    ungetc('\n', stdin); // inject the newline character into input buffer

    do {
        printf("Enter your selection\n");
        printf("\ti: insert a new entry\n");
        printf("\td: delete an entry\n");
        printf("\ts: search an entry\n");
        printf("\tp: print all entries\n");
        printf("\tq: quit \n");

        flush();    // flush the input buffer. To be discussed later
        ch = tolower(getchar());
        branching(ch);
    } while (ch != 113);

    return 0;
}

void flush() {  // flush the input buffer. To be discussed later
    int c;
    do {
        c = getchar();
    } while (c != '\n' && c != EOF);
}


void branching(char c) {    // branch to different tasks
    switch (c) {
    case 'i':
        insertion();
        break;
    case 's':
        search_person();
        break;
    case 'd':
        delete_person();
        break;
    case 'p':
        print_all();
        break;
    case 'q':
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid input\n");
    }
}

int insertion() {    // insert a new entry at the end
    if (tail == max) {
        printf("There are no more places to insert.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter name, phone, email, degree:\n");
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].name);
        // &directory[tail].name is an array. No "&" is needed
        scanf("%d", &directory[tail].phone, sizeof(directory[tail].phone));
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].email);
        scanf("%s", &directory[tail].degree);
        tail++;
        printf("The number of entries = %d\n", tail);
        return 0;
    }
}

int print_person(int i) {
    // print all information one person in the directory
    printf("\n\nname = %s\n", directory[i].name);
    printf("email = %s\n", directory[i].email);
    printf("phone = %d\n", directory[i].phone);
    printf("degree = %s\n", &directory[i].degree);
    return 0;
}

int print_all() {
    // print all information each person in the contactbook
    int i;

    if (tail == 0) {
        printf("No entries found.");
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < tail; i++) {
            print_person(i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int search_person() {      // print phone and email via name
    char sname[30]; int  i;
    char *p = sname;

    printf("Please enter the name to be searched for:\n");
    scanf("%s", sname);     //sname is an array, no & needed

    for (i = 0; i<tail; i++)
        if (strcmp(p, directory[i].name) == 0) {
            print_person(i);
            return i;

        }

    printf("The name does not exist.\n");
    return -1;
}
int delete_person() {
    int i, k;
    k = search_person();
    if (k == -1) {
        printf("The name does not exist.\n"); return -1;
    }
    else {
        for (i = k; i<tail; i++) {
            strcpy(directory[i].name, directory[i + 1].name);
            directory[i].phone = directory[i + 1].phone;
            strcpy(directory[i].email, directory[i + 1].email);
            printf("The index deleted is: %d\n", k);
        }
        tail--;
        return k;
    }
}
```

I have managed to answer a few questions that I need to for my assignment but I cant seem to figure two of them.

Questions:

2. Further modify insertion() function, so that the new person will be inserted into the directory (array) at the sorted place by the person’s name (keep the data in the array sorted by name in ascending order).
3. Modify search_person() function. Use a while loop to replace the for loop, In the loop, use pointer operation, instead of array operation, to iterate through the array elements.

For Question 2 this is the code that I have to modify:

```
int insertion() {    // insert a new entry at the end
    if (tail == max) {
        printf("There are no more places to insert.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter name, phone, email, degree:\n");
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].name);
        // &directory[tail].name is an array. No "&" is needed
        scanf("%d", &directory[tail].phone, sizeof(directory[tail].phone));
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].email);
        scanf("%s", &directory[tail].degree);
        tail++;
        printf("The number of entries = %d\n", tail);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I am completely confused as to what I should be doing here. I have sat here looking at the code and have no idea how to approach it. Even the question itself is confusing to me.

For Question 3 the code to modify is:

```
int search_person() {      // print phone and email via name
    char sname[30]; int  i;
    char *p = sname;

    printf("Please enter the name to be searched for:\n");
    scanf("%s", sname);     //sname is an array, no & needed

    for (i = 0; i<tail; i++)
        if (strcmp(p, directory[i].name) == 0) {
            print_person(i);
            return i;

        }

    printf("The name does not exist.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

So I think I managed to do the pointer operation part(although I am not 100% sure I did it correctly). The thing that I am confused on is how to use a while loop to replace the for loop. I have tried a few while loops but it always says that the "name" I searched for does not exist.

If someone could explain to me how I should approach these problems and explain to me what I should do that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: i think you can shrink it down to 1 gram of code first. nobody will try to read your ton.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) -- two names for the same basic idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second (for to while loop) one is much easier.
I'll just show you the generic way to convert for loops to while loops, and let you do your code, since you're trying to learn how to do this. Here's an example for loop:

```
int x;
for(x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

Now let's make a while loop that does the same thing:

```
int x;
x = 0;
while(x < 10)
{
    //do stuff here

    x++;
}
```

A for loop has three parts, the initialization, the condition, and the incrementor.

for(*initialization*, *condition*, *incrementor*)

The initialization only happens once, when the for loop is first reached.

The condition is done the after the initialization the first time, and then every time the top of the loop is reached again, to see if the loop should be carried out once more, or should be skipped.

The incrementor happens each time after the loop is carried out once through.

A while loop only has a condition. The initialization can just be added right before the while loop, and the incrementor can just be added as the very last thing in the while loop.

For your first problem, with the inserting in alphabetical order by name, you actually have to move other things in the array. Say we have four things in an array:

```
a e i o
```

Now say we want to add in g. We need to first check where it should go. So we look at the elements one by one, and if the element we're looking at should come after g, then we should put g in before the element we're looking at. In this case we would look at `a`, `e`, and then when we look at `i` we would know that g should come first. so we know we want g to go in the spot `i` is in. To make that spot empty, we have to move everything else in the array to the right, or towards the tail of the array. We have to do this starting at teh end. We move `o` into a spot one higher, and make that the new tail. Then we scoot `i` one over as well. That means we have an array with a gap (I'll use an underscore for the empty spot):

```
a e _ i o
```

Now we can just put out new element in the empty spot we made.

```
a e g i o
```

And there ya go! Now just take that algorithm and code it up! If you're having trouble, I'll be happy to flesh out the details more with you.

Comment: WOW! I loved your explanation of the while and for loops. I was able to look at your example and apply it to my code and it worked! As for the 2nd question, I understand what it is that I have to do, but I am not sure HOW to do it. Could you help me get started on it?

Answer (score 0):

For question 3 you could use arthimetic of pointers.

```
int search_person() {      // print phone and email via name
char sname[30]; int  i;
char *p = sname;

printf("Please enter the name to be searched for:\n");
scanf("%s", sname);     //sname is an array, no & needed

 i = 0;
 while(i<tale){

    if (strcmp(p, ((directory + i )->name)) == 0) {
        print_person(i);
        return i;}
     i++;

    }

printf("The name does not exist.\n");
return -1;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method to sort the `directory` array after insertion.

```
void dir_copy(struct person* src, struct person* dest)
{
    // since you are using arrays inside person structs
    // if dynamic memory is used, copy each string separately
    memcpy(src,dest,sizeof(struct person));
    return;
}

void dir_sort(struct person* dir, int dir_size)
{
    struct person temp;
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < dir_size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dir_size - 1; j++) {
            if (strcmp(dir[j].name, dir[j + 1].name) > 0) {
                dir_copy(&temp,&dir[j]);
                dir_copy(&dir[j],&dir[j + 1]);
                dir_copy(&dir[j + 1],&temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

int insertion() {    // insert a new entry at the end
    if (tail == max) {
        printf("There are no more places to insert.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        printf("Enter name, phone, email, degree:\n");
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].name);
        // &directory[tail].name is an array. No "&" is needed
        scanf("%d", &directory[tail].phone);
        scanf("%s", directory[tail].email);
        scanf("%s", &directory[tail].degree);
        tail++;
        printf("The number of entries = %d\n", tail);
        dir_sort(&directory,tail);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And using

```
scanf("%d", &directory[tail].phone, sizeof(directory[tail].phone));
```

will throw a compiler warning

```
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
         scanf("%d", &directory[tail].phone, sizeof(directory[tail].phone));
         ^
```

because their is not formating string provided for `scanf` to match the 3rd argument and which is anyhow is not a variable. i don't see any need for it.

if you want to print enum, use a getter function to get string instead of a ambiguous integer variable.

```
const char* getDegreeName(enum education degree) 
{
   switch (degree) 
   {
      case diploma: return "diploma";
      case bachelor: return "bachelor";
      /* etc... */
   }
}
```

similarly while getting the degree value use `setDegree` to compare the user input string and set the enum, instead of reading the string to a enum value, its not wise.

if you want to use `while` loop instead of `for` see others answers or google it, you will get lots of materials,

lastly, in `C` array variable is nothing but a const pointer, so you can use pointer arithmetic anytime instead of using array representation.
that means, 
`directory[i]` is same as `*(directory*i)`